# Practice for storing files for classes

Tags: php, file, directory, structure, file-management

How do you store files that are to be used in a class.

For example the class file itself, then images used in that class. Or do you not use images in the class, but just return an output to the main page which in turn uses the images?

Recently I have been problems deciding whether to put the images used by a class in the global directory for the website or to create its own directory. This has just stricken me as I realised that a class such as for image manipulation or db manipulation can be used with other projects and it might be hard to try and find the related images in the global folder when migrating them.

So how do you store the images used in your classes? Or do you not return a printed output ever from a class?

The programming language used in this case is PHP.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "images used in your classes." Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Jordan The images that are output with the content printed out by the class itself.

Comment: For any but the smallest projects I *strongly* recommend using a templating system--[Smarty](http://inception.davepedu.com/) is good and well-supported but there are many others--and keeping all markup separate from your application logic. This is sometimes called [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and is important to consider in any project of medium to large size.

Answer (score 3):

Images are stored in a separate folder. For one, images must be reached by the client (browser), while the php files (except for a couple that are actually used in urls) can be kept outside the document folder.

The exact path of images and others files is stored in a configuration. This is just a small PHP file that keeps a list of settings. You should not hardcode the path to your images folder in your classes.

Answer (score 1):

this is the structure I use

```
/includes
  All the clases that you have
/logs
  Log files
/public_html 
  All the pages visible to the user
  /css
  /javascript
  /images
```

You can have a config.php file where you have something like this

```
define("LIB_PATH", '/includes/');
define("IMG_PATH", '/public_html/images/');
```

etc.

That gives you the benefit of using absolute paths in a short, simple and understandable way